# Transform derivative term of 2nd order

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've a question regarding conversion of derivative. I want to get rid of the term $\partial \phi \over \partial R$. So i do the following:
${\partial \phi \over \partial R} = {\partial \phi \over \partial X}{\partial X \over \partial R}$
The term ${\partial \phi \over \partial X}$ is very welcome, as i know it. ${\partial X \over \partial R}$ is also ok.

Now, how can i do that with the 2nd derivative?

${\partial^2 \phi \over \partial R^2}$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should go to the math stackexchange site, but that's not a selectable site above.

Comment: Yes, this question probably should be migrated to Math.SE (if they want it).

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule:$\dfrac{\partial(uv)}{\partial x}=u\dfrac{\partial(v)}{\partial x}+v\dfrac{\partial(u)}{\partial x}\ $ :
$${\partial^2 \phi \over \partial R^2}={\partial  \over \partial R}\left({\partial \phi \over \partial R}\right)={\partial  \over \partial R}\left({\partial \phi \over \partial X}\cdot {\partial X \over \partial R}\right)={\partial \phi \over \partial X}\cdot {\partial  \over \partial R}\left({\partial X \over \partial R} \right)+{\partial X \over \partial R}\cdot {\partial  \over \partial R}\left({\partial \phi \over \partial X} \right)$$
$$={\partial \phi \over \partial X}\cdot{\partial^2 X \over\partial R^2}+{\partial X \over \partial R}\cdot{\partial^2\phi \over\partial R \; \partial X}$$

Comment: You swapped the order of the two terms in the final line, which makes this a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. Hope it's clearer now ;)